# IntelliJ Idea: JUnit Test Class template depending on condition

Tags: java, unit-testing, templates, intellij-idea, junit

I often write tests of different types. Depending on test type it might have different setup.

For instance all my service tests have the following annotation under class declaration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = NONE)
```

All controller tests have these annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WithMockUser
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
```

Another tests have different setup, etc.

Every time when I create a test I have to copy-paste this part from another test.

I'm looking for a solution that will help me automate this process in IntelliJ Idea.

**Q:** Is there any way to define `JUnit Test Class` templates which work differently depending on the type of the test?

Let's say class name ends with word "Service" - its generated test should use one template, if class name ends with "Controller" - its test should use another one, etc.

It is also possible to detect test type by package name or some other conditions like class content.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I personally use a ["live template"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-code-constructs-by-live-templates.html) to insert "usual"  `@RunWith` etc  or other stuff

Comment: @RC I haven't thought about that, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JUnit code generation templates can be found under Settings > File And Code templates > Code.

You can't really create separate code templates, but what you could do is add logic to the existing templates. They use Velocity based directives. 
So if, for example, we take the existing JUnit 4 template:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
#parse("File Header.java")

public class ${NAME} {
  ${BODY}
}
```

We can modify it to the following:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
#if($CLASS_NAME.contains("Service"))
//Import whatever you need for services here.
#end
#if($CLASS_NAME.contains("Controller"))
//Import whatever you need for controllers here.
#end
#parse("File Header.java")
#if($CLASS_NAME.contains("Controller"))
#set($CLASS_SUFFIX = ".class" )
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RunWithMock
@WebMvcTest(controllers = $CLASS_NAME$CLASS_SUFFIX)
#end
#if($CLASS_NAME.contains("Service"))
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = NONE)
#end
public class ${NAME} {
  ${BODY}
}
```

This way if you generate a new JUnit 4 test class through the context menu (hit alt-enter on the class name of the class you want to test and generate new test) it will generate different output if the name of the class to test contains 'Controller' or 'Service'. You might want to change that to endswith instead of contains depending on whatever naming conventions you use. 
I've left out the actual import statements in both cases, but I'm sure you'll be able to add those.